# Unable to obtain data from JSONObject when trying to collect a boolean type

Tags: java, android, json

In my application I currently have a ListView adapter hooked up to a Records class I made and what I'm trying to achieve is to grab the boolean values from my JSONObject and sync them along with my Checkbox.

**ChecklistActivity.java**

```
    public class ChecklistActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    private ChecklistAdapter mAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checklist);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mAdapter = new ChecklistAdapter(this);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        fetch();

    }

    private void fetch() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String passedURL = intent.getStringExtra("jsonData");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                passedURL,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        try {
                            List<Record> records = parse(jsonObject);

                            mAdapter.swapImageRecords(records);
                        }
                        catch(JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.this, "Unable to obtain data: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        Toast.makeText(ChecklistActivity.this, "Unable to fetch data: " + volleyError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        ParseApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().add(request);

    }

    private List<Record> parse(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        ArrayList<Record> records = new ArrayList<Record>();

        Intent iin= getIntent();
        Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
        String arrayName =(String) b.get("jsonArray");

        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray(arrayName);

        for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonImage = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = jsonImage.getString("id");
            String value = jsonImage.getString("value");

            // Checkbox
            JSONObject jsonObject = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("checklistData");
            Boolean checkBoxValue = jsonObject.getBoolean(id);

            Record record = new Record(id, value, checkBoxValue);

            records.add(record);
        }

        return records;
    }

}
```

**Record.java**

```
    public class Record {
    private String id;
    private String value;
    private boolean checkBoxValue;


    public Record(String id, String value, boolean checkBoxValue) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.checkBoxValue = checkBoxValue;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public boolean getCheckBoxValue() {
        return checkBoxValue;
    }
}
```

**ChecklistAdapter.java**

```
public class ChecklistAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Record> {

    CheckBox checkBox;

    public ChecklistAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.checklist_item);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.checklist_item, parent, false);

        }

            TextView desc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            final Record dataRecord = getItem(position);

            desc.setText(dataRecord.getValue());
            checkBox.setChecked(dataRecord.getCheckBoxValue());

            final JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
            try {
                myObject.put(dataRecord.getID(), true);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        JSONObject jsonObject = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("checklistData");

        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();

            public void onClick(View v) {

                boolean checkBoxValue = true;

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("checklistData", myObject);
                    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), idSelected,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is unchecked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

            public void swapImageRecords(List<Record> objects) {
                clear();

                for (Record object : objects) {
                    add(object);
                }

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }


        }
```

The issue seems to be in the `ChecklistActivity.java` file when assigning a boolean value from my JSONObject.

As seen in `ChecklistActivity.java` I declared a JSONObject which looks like this

```
{ "1ed1": true, "1ed2": false, "1ed3": true, "1ed4": false, "1ep1": true, "1ed2": false, "1ep3": true, "1c1": false, "1c2": true, "1c3": false, "1c4": true, "1c5": false, "1c6": true, "2ed1": false, "2ed2": true, "2ed3": false, "2ep1": true, "2ep2": false, "2ep3": true, "2c1": false, "2c2": true, "2c3": false, "2c4": true, "2c5": false, "2c6": true, "3ed1": false, "3ed2": true, "3ed3": false, "3ep1": true, "3ep2": false, "3c1": true, "3c2": false, "3c3": true, "3c4": false, "3c5": true, "3c6": false, "4ed1": true, "4ed2": false, "4ed3": true, "4ep1": false, "4ep2": true, "4c1": false, "4c2": true, "4c3": false, "4c4": true, "4c5": false }
```

Inside that file the there are two String

id equal to a key in the JSONObject
value equal to a value in the JSONObject

both of these are working fine

I'm trying to achieve assigning each checkBox a boolean value so In order for me to do that I must declare a proper boolean that retrieves a JSON Key and it's boolean value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by adding this in my `ChecklistAdapter.java` Class

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("checklistData");
    String id = dataRecord.getID();
    Boolean checkIDValue = jsonObject.optString(id).equals("true");


    checkBox.setTag(getItem(position));

    if (checkIDValue) {

        checkBox.setChecked(true);

    } else {

        checkBox.setChecked(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your get value to string :

```
Boolean checkBoxValue = jsonObject.optString(id).equals("true");
```